# I have xandros Linux and when I enter "apt-get update" it says "failed to fetch"

Tags: linux, apt, software-updates

I have xandros Linux and I am doing a test with it; when I put `apt-get update` in the terminal it gives me this error.

[image: apt-get update errors]

I want it to get updates from the Ubuntu server not the xandros server because it doesn't work.

Comment: I know this is a old Linux OS but I am trying to do a experiment with this Linux Os but I need the apt-get update for it to work

Comment: How *old* is that equipment? I remember mine ASUS with Xandrus was like what, 10 years old?

Answer (score 2):

Xandros support was discontinued in 2007, I am afraid.

Even back in the day, even though Xandros received an injection of money from Asus, a couple of months after buying my ASUS netbook I had to install Debian due lack of updates.

If my memory does not fail me Xandros was based in Ubuntu or Debian with a lightweight X interface.

You will have to install another more recent Unix/Linux distribution.

> Xandros is a line of operating systems created by Xandros Corporation.
>   Xandros Desktop was a Linux distribution. The name Xandros is derived
>   from the X Window System and the Greek island of Andros. Wikipedia
>   Latest release: 4.2 / 26 July 2007

I also had similar woes trying to use a recent Linux distribution at the end of last year on a contemporary machine of mine, an ASUS EeePC netbook 701 4G (those came with Xandros). Debian 9 would not boot.

The processor is also not supported anymore by recent Debian distributions (and others - Debian 9 dropped support for 32-bit Atoms).

At the end, I prefer to go instead with the latest version of FreeBSD (32-bits), as it will get more support in the future, offering the path to upgrade for new versions, than going to a dead end with Debian 8.